# How does one FTP a directory with multiple sub-directories?

Tags: ftp

I need to ftp a directory over to another system and I don't want to have to recreate all the folders on the other system by hand. How would I do this?

EDIT: I can't install anything so rsync etc are out....can only use windows native stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up zipping the directory and ftping it over as a binary and then unzipped it.

Not exactly ideal but works if you can unzip it on the other end.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @satanicpuppy suggestion, WinSCP ( http://winscp.net/eng/index.php). There is a "portable" form that doesn't require installing. I have used it to manage entire old-school websites, where each section contained an entire directory of `.html` and related files and sub-directories. And GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Using windows-native FTP, I don't know of any way to do it besides directory by directory. FTP as a protocol doesn't traverse directory trees: it reads the directory, decides it's not a file, and skips it.

Are you not allowed to *install* any software, or are you not allowed to run any executables? If you can run an .exe, you might try downloading a binary like pscp, or psftp (which supports batch scripting). They don't need to be installed, and it may give you a few more options.

Comment: I can't install, completely forgot about running executables.

Comment: @CheesePls: I love SCP partly because it supports the recursive flag that lets you move subdirectories without scripting. If the server you're copying to allows ssh, I'd recommend giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If the folders are empty, you might have to create an empty file in each before FTPing them.

Comment: folders are not empty...the all have either files,folders or a combination of both inside.